# Using c++ library in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying include c++ library (DLL) in my c# project but every time I do that I get following error message in VS2008, any suggestions?

**EDIT:** It's a C++ MFC DLL

> ```
> ---------------------------
> Microsoft Visual Studio
> ---------------------------
> A reference to 'C:\Users\cholachaguddapv\Desktop\imaging.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and
> that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
> ```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If it is a "normal" DLL (not COM, not managed C++), you cannot add a reference like this. You have to add p/invoke signatures (external static method definitions) for the exports you want to call in your DLL.

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll")]
public static extern int ExportToCall(int argument);
```

Have a look at the [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute in the online help.

Answer (score 10):

If it's a straight C++ library then it's not possible to reference it in this way.

You have two options, you can compile the C++ library as an assembly an expose the unmanaged code with a C++/CLI wrapper.

-or-

You can use some p/invoke calls if the library exposes it's functionality via a C API.

Could you expand the question a bit to include some details about how you normally call imaging.dll from c++?

Answer (score 7):

if it is a unmanaged dll you cannot add a reference to it.
You have to invoke it using pinvoke or the likes of it:

```
public classFoo

{

[DllImport("myunmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

private extern static int UnmanagedFunction(int type, int dest);

}
```

If you wanna convert it to a managed dll take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx

If you wanna know some more about pinvoke and dllimport take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx

Cheers

Comment: I realize this is super old, but the links are now broken.

Answer (score 3):

Calling convention and memory model difference between managed code (C#) and non-Managed code (WIn32 C++) make them incompatible.

However, .NET include a bridge technology for COM objects, so if you imaging DLL were a COM object, it could be made to work.  It is, however, apparently not a COM object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a clean C++ DLL where you only export C compatible functions, then you can use P/Invoke to use those functions. If you turn that C++ DLL into a COM DLL with a Type Library, using it is even easier: you can import the type library into .NET and .NET wrappers (called Runtime Callable Wrappers) are created for you.