# C++ library in C# - Inherit Classes

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use a C++ library (GAlib) in my C# project, in Visual Studio 2010.

I built the library to get the .lib and, thanks for your useful advice:

[Using c++ library in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772041/using-c-library-in-c-sharp)

I'm able to call the functions but I not able to create classes inheriting from the ones present within the library.

I have followed this guide

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx

I added

```
__declspec(dllexport) class GAEvalData {
public: 
. . . 
}
```

but using 
    dumpbin /EXPORT ga.lib 
to achieve the EntryPoint, I have no info.

I report the dumpbin output:

```
Dump of file ga.lib
File Type: LIBRARY
```

And nothing else.

Also inverting

```
class __declspec(dllexport) GAEvalData {
public: 
. . . 
}
```

it seems no work.

Any suggestions?

Is this the best way to inherit classes from external libraries?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Can you compile the C++ library in C++/CLI?

Comment: You might also want to look into SWIG or CXXI. | [CXXI github](https://github.com/mono/cxxi) | [CXXI introduction post](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html)

Comment: You need to ignore what's in that blog post.  The number of ways you'll blow your foot off are too numerous.  The failure mode is very nasty, debugging a corrupted GC heap is zero fun.  Writing a C++/CLI wrapper is by far the simplest way.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2691448/17034

Comment: Thanks Hans for reply, but I don't understand why I should write a C++/CLI wrapper since I use C#. I think I would rewrite the declaration of the class using [DllImport("cppexp.dll", EntryPoint = "??0CSimpleClass@@QAE@H@Z", ... ] for each Method of the Class, as suggested by blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/… but I need the Entry Point that dumpbin does not return. Hans, what I expected to do is exactly the one posted by "Micah 23 Jan 2009 11:07 PM" in the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should declare your class similar to:

```
#ifdef DBTOOL_EXPORTS
#define DBTOOL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DBTOOL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DBTOOL_API Class {}
```

Your C++ dll should define DBTOOL_EXPORTS. 
I think the idea is clear.
Hopefully it will help

Comment: That's not relevant to C# code, it doesn't #include a header file.

Comment: Thanks nogard for reply, but I think it is the same thing I've done.. I still cannot see Class object in my C# code, what I expected to do is exactly the one posted by "Micah 23 Jan 2009 11:07 PM" in the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx . Thanks in advance.