# Use C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, matlab, dll

I have a C# GUI, and a dll I compiled in matlab for C++.
I would like to call from my C# code to the dll functions.
I tried first to convert the C# code to CLI, but then saw it is not recommended.
Can I create one solution with 2 projects - one the C# GUI and one - wrap the c++ dll with C++ code and call it from the C# ?

Any reference will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772041/using-c-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++ dll's in C# by using `[DllImport]` attribute, it is described in this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ad74be1-8152-4bb4-8ced-3a400c04182d/dll-import-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: Thanks, I used this, but I'm having a problem, In the dll I have a function fl(int x, arr y), where arr type is defined in a c++ header file, which is included in the dll, but it is not recognized in the C# code

Comment: @matlabit You can assign it to [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) variable in C# and use it in the same way as in C++. `dymanic` keyword was introduced right to simplify inter-operational routine

Comment: Not so sure I get it, my dll function gets a type that C# cant recognize, I can compile it using dynamic, but how do I call the function ? for example:  [DllImport("myDll.dll")] extern static void myfunc(dynamic a, dynamic b); now say I want to use it, how can I assign a and b ?

Comment: @matlabit `dynamic` are the variables behavior of which are **not** being checked explicitly. For example, if `a` and `b` are C++ integer arrays, `Int32 aValue = (Int32)a[0]` must work.