# How to use C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I'm trying include c++ library (DLL) in my c# project but every time I do that I get following error message in VS2012

```
A reference to 'C:\Users\HiepDang\Desktop\mydll.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
```

When I'm trying add Com+ Component, I get following error message in window

> One or more files do not contain components or type libraries. These files cannot be installed.
>
> Error 80110425 occurred.
>
> An unknown error occured. You should check all documentation for a solution. If no further information is available, please contract technical support

I'm following thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823551/use-c-dll-from-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772041/using-c-library-in-c-sharp) but my problem not solved.

In C++, I can use dll like:

```
    //Header
    extern "C" __declspec( dllimport ) int mymethod(const char *key, char *data, size_t buflen);
    
    //Code test
    const char* key = "test";

    char* data = new char[1024];
    int buflen = 1024;
    int result = mymethod(key,data, buflen);
```

In C#, I use dll as:

```
    //define dll
    [DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int mymethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string key, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string data, uint buflen);

    //method test
    private static int testdll() 
    {
        string key = "123456789";
        string buf = string.Empty;
        mymethod(key, buf, 1024);
        return 0;
    }
```

Can you tell me any solutions to solve it.

P.s: My English is not good. I'm sorry if something inconvenient

Edited: I explain the variable in method in dll. "key" as string input has 8-13 characters, mymethod will be encrypted to generate "buf". I need variable of "buf".

Comment: As the links say, use `DllImport`.  **Do not** attempt to add a reference by right-clicking **References** and choosing **Add**.  Just use your existing `DllImport` c# code

Comment: @MickyDuncan: Thanks for reply. But C# code I have posted does not meet my requirement. When mymethod call, value of "buf" must change. Follow C# code, I just get an error message that "the value of 'key' is invalid". This happen when the variable of key not enough 8 characters.

Comment: Update your question to reflect these new requirements

Comment: Please put full exception message of the error when running your code. It will help us to distinguish what is exactly your problem.

Comment: @M.Mahdipour: Without exception error occurs with C# code. 


With C++ Code, when I call method with key = "123456789", I get buf = "2995796360". If key haven't between 8-13 characters, you must get mesage: "the value of 'key' is invalid". All messages return are defined by others. 


With C# Code, when I call method with key = "123456789", I get message like key haven't between 8-13 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you have to use `StringBuilder()`

```
//define dll
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int mymethod(string key, StringBuilder data, IntPtr buflen);

//method test
private static int testdll() 
{
    string key = "123456789";
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(1024);
    mymethod(key, buf, (IntPtr)buf.Capacity);
    string buf2 = buf.ToString()
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `size_t` is `IntPtr` in size, because it is 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on x64.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. I had to follow but still error occurred.

Comment: @HiepDang You have to put the `.dll` in the same folder of the `.exe`, and you have to know if your `.dll` has been compiled at 32 bits or at 64 bits. Then set the C# project to Properties->Build->Platform Target x86 if the dll is 32 bits and x64 if the dll is 64 bits.

Comment: mydll is 32 bits, then I set Platform Target x86 too. I think I must use C++/CLI to solved this bug. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have solved my problem. I have edited your code to improve answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your cpp project,
change

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllimport )
```

to

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )
```

And copy the generated cpp dll file "mydll.dll" to the outdir of your C# project.

By the way, you'd better use byte[] instead of char* for the second argument data if it is not a string but raw binary data.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mymethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string key, byte[] data, uint buflen);
```

byte array is automatically marshalled.

[Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use it like below.

```
var key = "A key";
var data = new byte[10];
//fill data
mymethod(key, data, (uint)data.Length);
```

Comment: Not like you think. Cpp code snippet you see using in Visual C++, and it can work good. But I want to use mydll.dll in C#, and I don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Also because my DLL is unmanaged (meaning it is an Unmanaged language like C or C++) then according to the specs of DllImport, "Indicates that the attributed method is exposed by a unmanaged DLL as a static entry point". Why can I not use this "DllImport"?
If its a c++ com object if you register it with regsvr32 you can add a reference to the dll in visual studio com references tab and usually visual studio creates an dll (I think its called a runtime callable wrapper) which you can see is created with the nameoflibrary.interop.dll. So MyExecRefsDll.dll if were a com object would become MyExexRefs.Interop.dll. But when you add the reference visual studio usually does this for you automatically in managed code.  If you create a c++ dll as a com object by using atl template in c++ it is easier to access from dotnet (Iam referencing unmanaged c++ code from a dll which references another dll file (No code copied from the second dll I just reference the tlb, lib, the dll file, and visual studio does everything else.