# Is there a cleaner way to merge C++ and C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, merge

I have an application i have designed and built in C# that uses some complex filtering. i have manually calculated filter values/parameters outside of my application and added them in. this method works temporarily, but ideally i want to generate my values inside my application. The values i generate come from C++. so my thought process is to create a standalone C++ application that i run from my C# application and generate the new values and save them into some .txt file that will automatically add the new filter in. is there a better way to do this without converting this code into C#?

Comment: You can create a C++ library and use it from C# directly with a function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using c++ library in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772041/using-c-library-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, here's a few ideas:

1. Like you suggested, you could save the values to a text file, and then read them in.
2. You could make the C++ program into a server, and connect the C# program to the C++ program over a TCP connection.
3. You could use a database like SQL Server to store the values.

I'm sure there's other ways to do it, but those are what came to mind.